# Ajax en PHP 8.1

Tags: ajax, email, php8

tenia la página web en PHP 5.3 y he decidido pasarla a lo mas actual PHP 8.1, todo me funciona correctamente, pero una función para enviar email que uso en un formulario sencillo no se ejecuta:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "enviarmail.php",
                method: "post",
                data: $('#contact_form').serialize(),
                success: function (res) {
                    if(res=="ok") {
                        $("#success_message").removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                    if(res=="error") $("#error_message").removeClass("hidden");
                }
            });
```

he puesto alert dentro del ajax pero no se ejecuta, justo antes si.

No se si hay que activar algo o cambiar algo para hacerlo compatible.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda ;)

Actualización: enviarmail.php

```
<?php
include_once("clases/class.emails.php");
$c_mail = new Emails();

include_once("clases/class.db.php");
$db = new bd();

if($_POST["nombreform"]=="programa")
{
    $c_mail->empresa=$_POST["empresa"];
    $c_mail->contacto=$_POST["contacto"];
    $c_mail->email=$_POST["email"];
    
    if($c_mail->sprograma()) { echo "ok"; $enviado=1; }
    else { echo "error"; $enviado=0; }
    
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `aqi111`.`programa` (`empresa`, `contacto`, `email`) VALUES ('".utf8_decode($_POST["empresa"])."', '".utf8_decode($_POST["contacto"])."', '".$_POST["email"]."')");
} 
else 
{
    $c_mail->nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
    $c_mail->email=$_POST["email"];
    $c_mail->mensaje=$_POST["mensaje"];
    
    if($c_mail->contacto()) { echo "ok"; $enviado=1; }
    else { echo "error"; $enviado=0; }
    
    $db->query("INSERT INTO `aqi111`.`contacto` (`nombre`, `email`, `mensaje`) VALUES ('".utf8_decode($_POST["nombre"])."', '".$_POST["email"]."', '".utf8_decode($_POST["mensaje"])."')");
}
?>
```

y la class.emails.php, hay mas variables de las necesito, pero entiendo que no deberia pasar nada, a ver si es el phpmailerautoload.php el que da problemas.

```
<?php
include_once("class.conexion.php");
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

Class Emails
{
    //definición de atributos de la clase
    var $cabeceras;
    var $asunto;
    var $cuerpo;
    var $texto_plano;
    
    var $email_dest;
    var $nombre_dest;
    
    var $nombreempresa;
    var $nombreempresautf8;
    var $emailempresa;
    var $urlempresa;
    var $urlimg;
    
    var $nombre;
    var $solucion;
    var $empresa;
    var $contacto;
    var $email;
    var $phone;
    var $comentario;
    var $address;
    var $localidad;
    var $codpos;
    var $provincia;
    var $pais;
    var $website;
    var $cifnif;
    var $telefono;
    var $actividad;
    var $empleados;
    var $volumen;
    var $porcentaje;
    var $botondesde;
        
    function sprograma() {
        
        $this->email_dest=$this->emailempresa;
        $this->email_dest="mr.spock84@hotmail.com";
        $this->nombre_dest=$this->nombreempresa;
        
        $this->asunto = utf8_decode("[".$this->nombreempresa."] Programa");
        $this->cuerpo='
            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;">
                  <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;">Programa</div><br />
                  <div>
                    <p>Datos del contacto:<br />
                    &emsp;&bull;&nbsp;Empresa: <strong>'.utf8_decode($this->empresa).'</strong><br>
                    &emsp;&bull;&nbsp;Persona de contacto: <strong>'.utf8_decode($this->contacto).'</strong><br>
                    &emsp;&bull;&nbsp;Email: <strong>'.$this->email.'</strong><br>
                    </p>
                  </div>
              </td>
            </tr>';
        
        if($this->enviar()) return true; else return false;
    }
    
    function contacto() {
        
        $this->email_dest=$this->emailempresa;
        $this->email_dest="mr.spock84@hotmail.com";
        $this->nombre_dest=$this->nombreempresa;
        
        $this->asunto = utf8_decode("[".$this->nombreempresa."] Contacto desde la web");
        $this->cuerpo='
            <tr>
              <td style="padding: 20px 10px 10px 10px;">
                  <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px;">Contacto desde la web</div><br />
                  <div>
                    <p>Datos del contacto:</p>
                    <p>
                    &emsp;&bull;&nbsp;<strong>Nombre:</strong> '.utf8_decode($this->nombre).'<br>
                    &emsp;&bull;&nbsp;<strong>Email:</strong> '.$this->email.'<br>
                    &emsp;&bull;&nbsp;<strong>Mensaje:</strong> '.$this->mensaje.'
                    </p>
                  </div>
              </td>
            </tr>';
            
        if($this->enviar()) return true; else return false;
    }

    function escribirlog($texto) 
    {
        $ddf = fopen('email.log','a');
        fwrite($ddf,"[".date("r")."]: $texto \n");
        fclose($ddf);
        
        if(strpos(strtoupper($texto),"ERROR")===0) {
            $ddf = fopen('error.log','a');
            $texto = $this->limpiamensaje($texto);
            fwrite($ddf,"[".date("r")."]: ".$texto."\n");
            fclose($ddf);
        }
    }
    
    function limpiamensaje($texto) 
    {
        $texto = strip_tags($texto);
        $texto = str_replace("&emsp;","",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("&nbsp;","",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("&bull;","",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("&eacute;","",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("&oacute;","",$texto);
        $texto = str_replace("&iacute;","",$texto);
        $texto = trim(preg_replace('/[ ]{2,}|[\t]/', '', $texto));
        $texto = str_replace("

","",$texto);
        
        return $texto;
    }

}
?>
```

y a ver si esta el lio en esto que pone algo de la versión PHP:

```
<?php
/**
 * PHPMailer SPL autoloader.
 * PHP Version 5
 * @package PHPMailer
 * @link https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/ The PHPMailer GitHub project
 * @author Marcus Bointon (Synchro/coolbru) <phpmailer@synchromedia.co.uk>
 * @author Jim Jagielski (jimjag) <jimjag@gmail.com>
 * @author Andy Prevost (codeworxtech) <codeworxtech@users.sourceforge.net>
 * @author Brent R. Matzelle (original founder)
 * @copyright 2012 - 2014 Marcus Bointon
 * @copyright 2010 - 2012 Jim Jagielski
 * @copyright 2004 - 2009 Andy Prevost
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html GNU Lesser General Public License
 * @note This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful - WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 */

/**
 * PHPMailer SPL autoloader.
 * @param string $classname The name of the class to load
 */
function PHPMailerAutoload($classname)
{
    //Can't use __DIR__ as it's only in PHP 5.3+
    $filename = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'class.'.strtolower($classname).'.php';
    if (is_readable($filename)) {
        require $filename;
    }
}

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.1.2', '>=')) {
    //SPL autoloading was introduced in PHP 5.1.2
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '>=')) {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload', true, true);
    } else {
        spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload');
    }
} else {
    /**
     * Fall back to traditional autoload for old PHP versions
     * @param string $classname The name of the class to load
     */
    function __autoload($classname)
    {
        PHPMailerAutoload($classname);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seguramente el ajax se esté ejecutando, no creo que el cambio de versión de PHP afecte a esto porque es JS, el problema lo tendrás seguramente dentro del archivo `enviarmail.php`, dando un error 500 o algo parecido y, ya que no está devolviendo un `success`, por culpa de dicho error, no está ejecutando los `removeClass`. De todas formas poco más puedo decirte con lo que has puesto...

Comment: es que antes del cambio de versión, si funcionaba. Si pongo un alert dentro de ajax, ¿no deberia salir? para saber si se ejecuta y que el problema esta en el enviamail.php

Comment: Como te digo, el provlema lo tendras en el archivo `enviarmail.php`, revisa los error logs de PHP a ver que te cuentan y sacaras mas información

Comment: Es bastante incoherente que por actualizar PHP deje de funonar JS, ¿no crees? Es como si actualizo el movil y deja de funcionarme el frigorifico y le culpo al movil... Tu problema 99% seguro esta en el archivo `enviarmail.php`

Comment: ok gracias, pues pondre alert en el enviarmail.php a ver si llega

Comment: Los alert son cosa de JS, PHP no sabrá responderte con un alert...

Comment: Tampoco se te puede ayudar mas sin saber que tiene el archivo `enviarmail.php`, sin saber como lo llamas o es ejecutado etc... Con un Ajax y diciendo que no va PHP nadie del foro podra ayudarte...

Comment: he editado el msg del principio con lo de enviarmail.php, voy a mirar el class.emails.php previendo que me lo pidas

Comment: Justo iba a decirte eso, porque mirando tu archivo no veo que haya nada que pudiera fallarte, quiza este equivocado pero no tiene niguna pinta... por lo que lo mas posible es que el problema este en los archivos que contienen las clases.

Comment: ya lo he puesto, tambien el phpmailerautoload

Comment: Seguramente el problema este en lo ultimo que has añadido, busca una version del paquete para la version de PHP 8.X o 8.1 si la hubiera concretamente

Comment: pues no veo nada :P

Comment: A la hora de realizar upgrades de versiones tienes que tener en cuenta que los paquetes externos que usas tendran versiones modernas y que como no los gestionas tu no te conviene meterte a actualziarlo, esto podria generar aun mas problemas... es mejor buscar versiones mas nuevas de los paquetes (que ademas tendra nuevas funcionalidades y mejor rendimiento), o si no exisitiera buscar un paquete diferente y amoldar tu codigo a este...

Comment: no consigo que funcione asi que bajaré de nuevo la version PHP

Comment: El problema no esta en la version de PHP, tienes que descargar la version del PHPMailer para PHP8.1 y amoldar tu codigo por posibles cambios que hayan hecho, de tu version a la nueva habra cambios que igual no son backward compatible.

Comment: De todas formas, hacer un cambio de versiones, sobre todo entre versiones tan lejanas como la 5.X y la 8.1 es algo delicado.. deberias ir una a una revisando todo lo que han cambiado y si te afecta revisando todo el codigo una y otra vez.... No es coger, cambiar la version y a funcionar. Nada es tan facil. Yo realice un cambio de versiones de PHP 5.4 a PHP 7.4, revise 1000 archivos 4 o 5 veces cada uno mirando los cambios de version entre la 5.4 y todas las intermedias hasta la 7.4... es un trabajo tedioso pero es lo que toca

Comment: Lo que dice @adrigo es correcto, no es bueno mantener paginas web en versiones viejas o **deprecated**, ya que son mas propensas y vulnerables a ataques maliciosos, si estas migrando de versión de PHP debes adecuar y actualizar el código de tu pagina, muchos métodos, fuciones, etc, cambian. No te confundas PHP y JS no tienen relación, son independientes.

Comment: En eso andamos, gracias

Comment: Que tal lo llevas? @Mr.Spock84

Comment: En principio esta todo bien, pero no funciona, veremos a la vuelta de vacaciones. Baje a php 8 pero igual.

Comment: Buenas, retomando el tema (aun no esta solucionado) e investigando el problema creo que esta en el PHPMailerAutoload que se ha actualizado y ya no es compatible con php 8.1. al igual que las clases de PhpMailer, pero realizando los cambios todavía continua igual. Si averiguo algo nuevo lo postearé a menos que alguien me de la solución antes ;)